# Re-Size Image to be same size same as emoji - iOS Custom Keyboard

Tags: ios, image, custom-keyboard

I have a custom keyboard application and have custom emojis (.png files) that users can use in iMessage. Users complain that when they copy and paste the custom emoji (.png file) into their iMessage application that the .png file is NOT the same size as the standard apple emojis (which is a font).

I have tried every size and resolution and can't seem to find the right pixel height or resolution to make my .png images to look the same as Apple's Emojis.

Goal: Make my .png files look like apple emojis when users are copy/paste them into iMessage.

Any thoughts or ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You can;t manage image size manually while you paste it in iMessage. It's depend device resolution specific.